# How to get the size of a struct field in Rust without instantiating it

Tags: rust, ffi, rust-bindgen

I have a structure with a byte array in it. This structure actually comes from the FFI bindings produced by bindgen, and its size is defined in C code using a macro, i.e.:

C code:

```c
#define FOO_SIZE 100

struct the_struct
{
    char foo[FOO_SIZE];
    /* other fields... */
};
```

Generated FFI bindings:

```rust
pub struct the_struct {
    pub foo: [::std::os::raw::c_char; 100usize],
    // other fields...
}
```

I want to make sure that the data coming from the Rust API side fits into `foo`. I also do not want to hard code `FOO_SIZE` in my Rust API, since it is subject to change.

I understand that this can be done by instantiating the struct first, but then again, that would require explicit initialization of `foo`, which seems to be impossible without knowing its size. Furthermore, it is an extra step I want to avoid.

Is it possible to somehow get the size of `foo` statically without instantiating the structure? If not, what would be the best approach? Changing C code is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the nightly channel I came up with this:

```rust
#![feature(raw_ref_op)]

pub struct the_struct {
    pub foo: [::std::os::raw::c_char; 100usize],
    // other fields...
}

fn main() {
    let foo_size: usize = {
        fn size<T>(_: *const T) -> usize {
            std::mem::size_of::<T>()
        }

        let null: *const the_struct = std::ptr::null();
        size(unsafe { &raw const (*null).foo })
    };

    println!("{}", foo_size);
}
```

As far as I can tell, `&raw const (*null).foo` is not UB because dereferencing a null-pointer to get another pointer is explicitly allowed. Unfortunately not only does this require the still unstable `raw_ref_op` feature, but because this dereferences a pointer, this also cannot be `const`.

Comment: Although I am reluctant to use nightly for the product I develop, this seems to be the closest to what I need. Thanks!

Comment: What about using `NonNull::dangling()` instead of `null`? Could it be used for this in stable?

Comment: @rodrigo No, you’d be creating a reference to an initialized object, which is UB.

Comment: @mcarton: Ah, I see. I would still need the `&raw` and then `dangling()` buys nothing over a plain old `null()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use closures to "simulate" evaluation of `my_struct::foo` without constructing it with the following:

```rust
pub struct the_struct {
    pub foo: [::std::os::raw::c_char; 100usize],
    // other fields...
}

pub fn main() {
    dbg!( get_size_of_return_type(|s: the_struct| s.foo) );
}

fn get_size_of_return_type<F, T, U>(_f: F) -> usize
where
    F: FnOnce(T) -> U
{
    std::mem::size_of::<U>()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45a51a065319b6b11e36eff70703ee49)

This just makes rust infer the return type of the closure, `U = [c_char; 100]` given a `fn(the_struct) -> U`, and returns it's size.

Answer (score 3):

This works in stable, and in `const` contexts starting in 1.58.

```rust
macro_rules! field_size {
    ($t:ident :: $field:ident) => {{
        let m = core::mem::MaybeUninit::<$t>::uninit();
        // According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/macro.addr_of_mut.html#examples,
        // you can dereference an uninitialized MaybeUninit pointer in addr_of!
        // Raw pointer deref in const contexts is stabilized in 1.58:
        // https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/89551
        let p = unsafe {
            core::ptr::addr_of!((*(&m as *const _ as *const $t)).$field)
        };

        const fn size_of_raw<T>(_: *const T) -> usize {
            core::mem::size_of::<T>()
        }
        size_of_raw(p)
    }};
}

pub struct Foo {
    pub foo: [u32; 34],
    // other fields...
}

// Stable as of 1.58:
const FOO_DATA_SIZE: usize = field_size!(Foo::foo);

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(field_size!(Foo::foo), 4 * 34);
}
```

The `addr_of!` macro is stable and works with raw pointers into `MaybeUninit<T>`, but not null pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it is possible to get the array size yet, but if you don't have too many such structures and the size doesn't change too often, I'd just declare the value explicitly:

```rust
pub const FOO_SIZE: usize = 100;
```

and then declare a function that will fail to compile if the hard-coded constant is wrong:

```rust
fn _assert_foo_size(s: &mut the_struct) {
    s.foo = [0; FOO_SIZE];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a viable approach, but in my circumstances it's not exactly suitable, because `FOO_SIZE` changes depending on the product build configuration, and implementing this logic in my Rust API makes the whole thing quite fragile. I will have to go more or less this way unless I find a better solution...