# How to get size of struct fields in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a struct like this.

```rust
pub struct MemTableEntry {
    pub key: Vec<u8>,
    pub value: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    pub timestamp: u128,
    pub deleted: bool,
}
```

I wanted to calculate the *size of* each field of the struct programmatically. What are the ways to do that?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I get the runtime memory size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613488/how-do-i-get-the-runtime-memory-size-of-an-object)

Comment: Each language aligns structs in memory in different ways.
a **sizeof** calls returns the byte size at which it is exactly placed in memory, not the actual size of the struct.
So you have to calculate it yourself for each field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the size of a struct field in Rust without instantiating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046063/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-struct-field-in-rust-without-instantiating-it)

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues It does not, but link of the first comment does.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the [std::mem::size_of_val](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html) and pass the reference of each fields. The returned type is `usize` which itself can be 4 or 8 bytes based on the target machine.

```rust
let entry = MemTableEntry{
    key: b"Hello".to_vec(),
    value: Some(b"World".to_vec()),
    timestamp: 123u128,
    deleted: false
};

let size = mem::size_of_val(&entry.key)
    + mem::size_of_val(&entry.value)
    + mem::size_of_val(&entry.timestamp)
    + mem::size_of_val(&entry.deleted);

assert_eq!(65, size);
```

**Note**: Please look at the @Caesar's comment below about memory.

Comment: What was the comment? It's gone now.